zshで一切コマンドが効かなくなってしまった
自分でも何が起こっているのかよくわからないんですが、Ubnutu上のZshで、コマンドがほとんど聞かなくなってしまいました。
環境は、ubuntu 24.04, wsl2, zshで、zshのフレームワークとしてohmyzsh、テーマにpowerlevel10pを使っています。
経緯としては、ホームディレクトリにzsh-abbrというプラグインをgit cloneしてパスを通そうとsourceしたところ、pyenvが不明？みたいな警告が出て、とりあえずもう一度sourceを叩いたらls, vim, catといった基本的なコマンドが一切使えなくなって（パスが通らなくなった？）しまいました。
一応、source, exec, whereだけは使えるようです。
下にスクショを貼り付けますので参照願います。
このままでは何もできません…お願いします。






手っ取り早くはターミナルを開き直してどうなるかを確認してみてください。

残念ながら変わりありません

.zprofile .zshenv .zshrc をスクリーンショットではなくテキストで開示してください。

zsh-abbrのサイトを見る限り、.zshrcを編集するとあるので、編集したものとして書きます。
編集により、環境変数PATHが設定されなくなったと予想します。
ですので、.zshrcの編集箇所を編集前の状態に戻すと復旧するかもしれません。
また、コマンドをフルパスで実行すれば、実行できるかもしれません。
(例: /bin/ls)
